# Why does my C# function returning the position of a letter in the alphabet work?

Tags: c#, function, letter, alphabet

I have a function that returns the position of a letter in the alphabet. How does it work?

This is how my C# looks like:

```
    private int CalculateLetterPosition(char cCharacter)
    {
        int iReturn = 0;
        int iCharacterValue = (int)cCharacter;
        if (iCharacterValue >= 97 && iCharacterValue <= 122)
        {
            iReturn = iCharacterValue - 96;
        }
        return iReturn;
    }
```

Comment: It seems to use ASCII character values. But to be honest, I'm a little confused how you could have written this code without understanding how it works.

Comment: ASCII codes, the letter `a` is integer 97 hence why it subtracts 96. But this question really doesn't belong here.

Comment: Only works for lowercase letters, though.

Comment: You should probably understand what the [Ascii *Table*](http://www.asciitable.com/) is.

Comment: @CrushaK.Rool ...and only for ASCII.

Comment: Beforehand I convert my string to lowercase.

Comment: I'm really interested, why everybody mentions ASCII? `char` represents `Unicode` symbol.

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm I'm going to disagree with this explanation. Getting letter number can be actual not only for English alphabet exactly because `char` is Unicode character. You can set hardcoded integer constants to 1072, 1105, 1071 and method will be returning actual Russian letter number for Russian alphabet for example. This is just a coincidence and historical reason there is English alphabet in the ASCII table, but not another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all letters(or `chars`) have numeric representations. Basically,

1. Your code casts the text char value to its [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) numeric value.
2. Subtracts 96 from the numeric value since 97 is the ASCII code for 'a'.
3. Final result will be the position in the alphabet.

For example:

You provide `b` to your function.

- `b` stands for `98` in ASCII table.
- `98 - 96 = 2`

Answer (score 0):

in the [ASCII](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange) code table the small "a" starts at position 97 in a row.
Therefore you only have to subtract 96 from its ASCII postion. Your code only works for lowercase letters, and only for letters within the ASCII range.

Comment: as a matter of simplicity